# Find Max with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to either filter or create another column to return the max date so I can filter on that column. There are 4 columns I am trying to use as criteria. My data looks like this.

```
Date      Time     Supplier     Terminal     Cost
8/21/18   1800        43           4         2.35
8/21/18   1030         3           5         2.27 
8/21/18   1045        43           4         2.25
8/20/18   1800         3           4         2.30
8/20/18   1800         3           5         2.37
```

I think the best way to filter is to create another column to return the max date and time for each supplier terminal combo. I want the data to be return like this. This was I can filter on True

```
 Date      Time     Supplier     Terminal     Cost     MaxValue
8/21/18   1800        43           4         2.35        True
8/21/18   1030         3           5         2.27        True
8/21/18   1045        43           4         2.25        False
8/20/18   1800         3           4         2.30        True
8/20/18   1800         3           5         2.37        False
```

Is something like this possible? Or could it be done using VBA?
Thanks in advance!

Update: Here is a link to the excel data that can be copied an pasted into excel

https://ethercalc.org/9xyxloijh5y9.html

The order in which I'm looking to match and find Max is a follows: Terminal>Product>Date>Time

With that I will have the latest date/cost for each supplier for each product per terminal. Hopefully seeing the data will help.

Comment: If you're looking for max date and time, wouldn't it be easiest to sort descending on date, then time, then supplier, then terminal?  Then the first line of each unique entry would be your max

Comment: Which, as it happens, lines up perfectly with your provided sample data which appears to be already sorted as such.

Comment: Would it help if I share my file in Zoho Reports so you can see it?